# Why does the GraphQl tutorial (Apollo Odyssey) indicate “Error! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0”?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

there!
Now, I’m trying GraphQl tutorial (Apollo Odyssey) and have one question about it.

At 1:43 of this video in [the GraphQl tutorial (Apollo Odyssey)](https://odyssey.apollographql.com/lift-off-part1/the-usequery-hook), the screen shows the json response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DagYd.png)

However, my screen shows the following message, **“Error! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0”** above, instead of the json response.

You can see the string of “undefined” too when I debug in the [client/src/pages/tracks.js (GitHub)](https://github.com/echizenyayota/odyssey-lift-off-part1/blob/master/client/src/pages/tracks.js#L28).

Why does the GraphQl tutorial (Apollo Odyssey) in my localhost indicate “Error! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0”, although I do programming following the video and the [document of ODYSSEY - LIFT-OFF I: BASICS](https://odyssey.apollographql.com/lift-off-part1).

I would like you to tell me how to solve this error.

In addition, I have already posted the [same question](https://community.apollographql.com/t/why-does-the-catstronaut-indicate-error-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/2320) in the community of the Apollo GraphQL but I've yet to get any answers or tips.

Thank you.

Comment: Really need to see the code here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, Mark. 
Thank you for your comment. 
I'll leave the comment in the question when I ask what I don't know next time. 
Actually, I've solved this question below.

https://community.apollographql.com/t/why-does-the-catstronaut-indicate-error-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/2320/4?u=echizenyayota

Answer (score 0):

In `src/index.js`, I did programming [like this](https://github.com/echizenyayota/odyssey-lift-off-part1/blob/560c7fbf0fb228722d7a26fb6f1aae145a3c2a75/client/src/index.js#L7-L10).

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

By replacing the `http://localhost:3000/` into `http://localhost:4000/`, I fixed the error.
Also, I noticed that you need to invoke two local hosts at the same time.

If you want to know the detail, you can ensure that below.

https://community.apollographql.com/t/why-does-the-catstronaut-indicate-error-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/2320/4?u=echizenyayota